# Golang InfluxDB client write point with _field key

Tags: go, influxdb

I want to write point InfluxDB with such signature:

```
{
"_field": "some_uuid",
"_value": float64,
"_time": "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
}
```

But uuid writes to "field" key instead of "_field", and "_field" key has default - "value".
[image]
How can i fix it?

This is my sample code:

```
import (
  "fmt"
  influxdb2 "github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-go/v2"
  "time"
)

type TagData struct {
    TagId     string  `json:"tag_id"`
    Value     float64 `json:"value"`
    Timestamp string  `json:"timestamp"`
}

func main() {
    inflClient := influxdb2.NewClient("my_url", "my_token")
    writeAPI := inflClient.WriteAPI("my_org", "my_bucket")

    data := TagData{
        TagId:     "d8f623a9-c255-4e0d-9c2f-126056875cef",
        Value:     300,
        Timestamp: "2023-12-11T15:35:42.343Z",
    }
    parsedTime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z", data.Timestamp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing time:", err)
        return
    }
    point := influxdb2.NewPointWithMeasurement("data").
        AddTag("field", data.TagId).
        AddField("value", data.Value).
        SetTime(parsedTime.UTC())
    writeAPI.WritePoint(point)
    writeAPI.Flush()
    inflClient.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone runs into the same problem - possible solutions are:

```
point := influxdb2.NewPointWithMeasurement("your_measurement").
    AddField(data.TagId, data.Value).
    SetTime(parsedTime.UTC())
```

```
point := influxdb2.NewPoint("your_measurement",
    map[string]string{},
    map[string]interface{}{data.TagId: data.Value},
    parsedTime.UTC())
```